# How can I formulate a linear constraint?

Tags: constraints

$C_t$ and $S_i$ are two decision variables.

(1) $C_t$=$C_{(t-1)}$+$D_i$ if t=$S_i$, $\forall${i,t}

(2) $C_t$=$C_{(t-1)}$, if $t\neq S_i$, $\forall${i,t}

How can I present the above two conditional equations as a linear constraint?
Appreciated!

Comment: The question is unclear.

Comment: I'm a little confused about the quantification here.  What if $t = S_3$ but $t \neq S_2$? Then from $(1)$ we get $C_t = C_{t-1} + D_3$, but from (2) we get $C_t = C_{t-1}$. Maybe you mean something like
(1) $\forall i\, \forall t, \,t = S_i \implies C_t=C_{(t-1)}+D_i$
and (2) $\forall t \left( (\forall i\,\, t \neq S_i)  \implies C_t=C_{(t-1)}\right)$?

Comment: also (2) implies if $S_i = S_j$ then $D_i = D_j$, is that right?

Comment: $t=\{1,2,3,...,T\}$, and $S_i$ can be a set of times between 1 and T.  If   $t=S_{i}$ at any point of time, then $C_t=C_{(t-1)}+D_i$. On the other hand, If   $t\neq S_{i}$ at any point of time, then $C_t=C_{(t-1)}$. These two conditions can be written as:
$$C_t= 
\begin{cases}
  \  C_{(t-1)}+D_i\hspace{1cm}\text{if } t=S_{i} \hspace{1cm}\forall{i,t}\\ 
   \ C_{(t-1)}\hspace{1cm} \text{if } t\neq S_{i} \hspace{1cm}  \forall{i,t}
\end{cases}$$